# Rabbit MQ create readonly user

Tags: rabbitmq, readonly

We got [Admin] [Monitoring] [Policymaker] [Management] [Impersonator] [None]
privileges for users in rabbit MQ.

In UI for rabbit, I need to create a user who needs only read access to queues(via UI), but not to create new queues / play with exchanges . How can i do it?

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

See the [rabbitmq access control](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html), and in detail the [permissions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#permissions)

In you case should be enough to do:
[image]

The user `myuser` can consume only from queues that starting from `myqueue`

**EDIT**

if you try to create a queue using the user `myuser`, you get this error:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gabriele. I have edited my question. Please check my question for further details. ta

Comment: if you follow the answer, the user can't create the queues, the button is enabled, but you will get an error

Comment: @Ramu when someone gives you instructions, you should actually try them out. In this case, all you have to do is _try_ to create a queue in the UI and it will become clear that Gabriele's instructions are correct.

Comment: With all respect I have tried it, somehow I’m able to still create a new queue. I thought something might be wrong at my end. Wish i could show what im doing, but couldn’t do it here.

Comment: @Ramu yes I think you are doing something wrong :) ! Updated the answer!